# SWIG wrapping issues with C++ --> python

Tags: python, c++, swig

I'm trying to wrap a C++ file that depends on another C++ file (global.cpp) by using SWIG. I was able to get the first one to work fine, but this nested dependence seems to cause an issue. Here is my setup:

### position.i

```
%module position
%include global.i
%{
  #include "pos.h"
%}
%include "pos.h"
%include "global.h"
... (functions declared)
```

## position.cpp

```
#include <algorithm> 
#include "global.h"
#include "pos.h"
...(functions implemented)
```

## position.h

prototypes

I then do this.

```
swig -c++ -python -builtin position.i
g++ -O2 -fPIC -c position.cpp
g++ -O2 -fPIC -c -I/Users/aaron/anaconda/include/python3.5m position_wrap.cxx
```

I have the two object files and then I bind them with

```
g++ -dynamiclib -lpython position.o global.o position_wrap.o -o _position.so
```

I've tried a number of different ways of doing this after perusing through SO and I have been totally stifled.

I get an error

```
 ...
 "_PyUnicode_FromFormat", referenced from:
      SwigPyObject_repr(SwigPyObject*) in position_wrap.o
      SwigPyPacked_repr(SwigPyPacked*) in position_wrap.o
      SwigPyPacked_str(SwigPyPacked*) in position_wrap.o
  "_PyUnicode_FromString", referenced from:
      _PyInit__position in position_wrap.o
      SWIG_Python_DestroyModule(_object*) in position_wrap.o
      SwigPyPacked_str(SwigPyPacked*) in position_wrap.o
  "_Py_DecRef", referenced from:
      SwigPyObject_repr(SwigPyObject*) in position_wrap.o
  "__PyObject_New", referenced from:
      _PyInit__position in position_wrap.o
...
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

with compilation. I've tried different linker flags by going to the path `python3-config --ldflags` states. I've added the `-std=libstdc++` flag. I once somehow got the module to generate, but upon import to python was faced with :

```
ImportError:   dlopen(/Users/aaron/Desktop/swigdPython/src/_position.cpython-35m-darwin.so, 2):
    Symbol not found: __Z10e_to_ed Referenced from:
        /Users/aaron/Desktop/swigdPython/src/_position.cpython-35m-darwin.so
    Expected in: dynamic lookup"
```

I'm at a loss trying to figure out the proper way to link these files and was hoping someone here had some insight.

Answer (score 2):

You should specify the library last on the link command line:

```
g++ -dynamiclib position.o global.o position_wrap.o -o _position.so -lpython
```

Comment: The result of this is a much smaller error message, but still receiving an undefined symbols error.

Comment: @Anisotropic: You may need to link with other libraries.  Which symbols are still undefined?

Comment: Compiler barfs out undefined "_PyInstanceMethod_New" , "_PyModule_Create2", "_PyUnicode_Concat", "_PyUnicode_FromFormat", "_PyUnicode_FromString" reference from the wrapper object. the invocation is `Thread model: posix
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.10.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -dylib -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.10.0 -o _sunposition.so sunpos.o global.o sunpos_wrap.o -lpython -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.0.2/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a`

Comment: Do you see the `libpython.dylib` in the `/usr/lib` directory?

Comment: Yes along with the 2.7 version of it

Answer (score 2):

The ordering might matter here, i.e.

```
g++ -dynamiclib position.o global.o position_wrap.o -lpython -o _position.so
```

instead of

```
g++ -dynamiclib -lpython position.o global.o position_wrap.o -o _position.so
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this to finally work using this command:

```
g++ -dynamiclib -o _position.so position_wrap.o position.o global.o -
I/Users/aaron/anaconda/include/python3.5m/ - L/Users/aaron/anaconda/lib/ -I/Users/aaron/Desktop/swigdPython/src -lpython3.5
```

I then couldn't get the module to load until exporting an environment variable:

`export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/aaron/anaconda/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`